# How can a specific row of (RGB) values in numpy be sought for, in order to replace said row with a different set of (RGB) values?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I created a numpy array from an image (RGB value) and need to configure the values in it. Setting a single-valued condition (searching through just the columns) to search for the given value and then applying the needed configuration, applies the configuration to the whole row, which would be fine if nothing but the columns would matter.

I need to specify when the configuration is to be applied to a row, and for that I would need to set the condition such that every value of the given row is actually considered, instead of solely searching for the values of a column, and instead of the search being based on a single value of the column, of the whole array.

Converting all the RGB values into Hex, then configuring the values as needed (as they'd be 1D), then converting all the Hex values to RGB, and then print the result, if absolutely necessary, would be an option.

From here the introduction to the code I used and the results I have gotten are described.

The used code in order to create an array from an image (dimensions in this case: 1366 x 768 & .PNG & RGB), and the result:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

path = "path_img_file.png"
oArray = np.array(Image.open(path).convert('RGB'))
print(oArray)


#result:
..
..
[[223 223 213]
  [223 223 213]
  [222 222 212] #RELEVANT ROW LATER
  ...
  [224 222 212]
  [222 221 211] #RELEVANT ROW LATER
  [225 223 213]]]
```

With `oArray[oArray[:, :, 0] == 222] = [1, 2, 3]` the first column of every row (as per `[:, :, 0]`), whenever the value 222 `.. == 222]`is present, that whole row of where 222 is present will equal `[  1   2   3]`, the code to achieve that and its result is:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

path = "path_img_file.png"
oArray = np.array(Image.open(path).convert('RGB'))
oArray[oArray[:, :, 0] == 222] = [1, 2, 3] #THIS IS THE CODE
print(oArray)

#result:
..
..
 [[223 223 213]
  [223 223 213]
  [  1   2   3] #AFFECTED ROW
  ...
  [224 222 212]
  [  1   2   3] #AFFECTED ROW
  [225 223 213]]]
```

My intention is to only affect the latter row, the row that originally was `[222 221 211]`, so that `[222 222 212]` remains as it was originally. I thought using something along the lines of `oArray[oArray[:, :] == [222, 222, 211]] = [1, 2, 3]` would work, but I do not seem to be able to apply that effectivly, the code if used and its result would look like so:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

path = "path_img_file.png"
oArray = np.array(Image.open(path).convert('RGB'))
oArray[oArray[:, :] == [222, 222, 211]] = [1, 2, 3] #NOTICE oArray[:, :, 0] IS oArray[:, :] HERE
print(oArray)


#result:
oArray[oArray[:, :] == [222, 222, 211]] = [1, 2, 3]
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 14743 output values where the mask is true
```

How could I ensure that whenever the row is specifically `[222 221 211]` that `[1, 2, 3]` is printed?
If absolutely necessary (introduction), how could I convert the RGB values into Hex, and the Hex values into RGB?

Thanks for every comment and answer, and thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: It's wordy, but you can do `oArray[(oArray[:,:,0]==222) & (oArray[:,:,1]==222) & (oArray[:,:,1]==211)]`.

Comment: Thanks! Did:
`oArray[(oArray[:,:,0]==222) & (oArray[:,:,1]==221) & (oArray[:,:,2]==211)] = [1, 2, 3]`

It works! =)

Comment: or `(oArray==[222,222,211]).all(axis=2)`

Comment: So `oArray[(oArray==[222,222,211]).all(axis=2)]=[1,2,3]`

Comment: @chrslg Thanks! This appears to accuratly showcase the row where the input value is present, will apply this! =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
mask = np.all(oArray == [222, 221, 211], axis=2)
oArray[mask] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Will consider this option when possible!